# Are there any free programs that will allow me to convert 3d files exported from Photoshop into Blender?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, 3d, blender

The title says it all.  I've created a simple heart shaped extrusion in Photoshop that I'd like to import into Blender for editing.  So far none of the file formats I've exported to (from the ps side) are recognized by Blender.

Is there a free program that will allow me to convert any of the PS 3D file formats to something I can use in Blender?

Comment: Shouldn't be any need. There's a 3D export in `3D > Export 3D Layer` The format you likely want is `OBJ`

Answer (score 1):

Blender can actually import Wavefront (.obj) files using File > Import from the context menu:

[image: File > Import > Wavefront (.obj)]

You just can't use File > Open to open .obj (Wavefront) files is all.